Optimizing LazyColumn Recomposition Jetpack Compose
I am developing an app using Jetpack Compose that organizes items into three lists ("List 1", "List 2", "List 3"), each represented by a sealed class. I am trying to prevent compsoable from constant recompositions, even one isLoading change, causes to recompose whole composable tree as observed in Layout inspector also can't apply animations to these items when they change position  or are inserted/deleted using animateItemPlacement(), but the animations aren't triggering because the LazyColumn is continuously recomposing whenever the state updates.
state is held in ViewModel and and also updated from there like this :
casualViewState.updateState { copy(loading = loading) }

Here's a simplified version of my implementation :
data class ListViewModelState(
    val list1Items: List<ItemType>,
    val list2Items: List<ItemType>,
    val list3Items: List<ItemType>,
    val isLoading: Boolean
)

sealed class ItemType(val id: String) {
    data class ItemDetailA(val detail: Detail) : ItemType(detail.id)
    data class ItemDetailB(val note: Note) : ItemType(note.id)
}

@Composable
fun GenericListView(state: ListViewModelState) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(state.list1Items, key = { it.id }) { item ->
            GenericItemView(item)
        }
        items(state.list2Items, key = { it.id }) { item ->
            GenericItemView(item)
        }
        items(state.list3Items, key = { it.id }) { item ->
            GenericItemView(item)
        }
    }
}

despite all efforts lists are still recomposing entirely on every state update. What could be causing the LazyColumn to continuously recompose entirely instead of only the specific items that have changed?
I've tried using unique keys and @Stable & @Immutable annotations to manage recompositions more efficiently. Also tried removing passing parameters and modifiers created with composed method among composables.

because every time your state changes the entire GenericListView method has to recompose and since you have every list being built in there its doing everything again. Split your different lists into different composables and separate your lists into their own individual states

those 3 lists resemble 1 scrolling screen. if i divide those 3 lists in different composables with 3 different LazyColumn they will scroll independently no ?

Actually, the element in the list are skipping recomposition if you see the Layout Inspector. However, composable GenericListView is supposed to recomposed, since its parameter state is changed every time you add the element in the list.
To prevent this, pass the State<ListViewModelState> to GenericListView or make each and every components of the ListViewModelState have their own state. I would choose the latter one.
data class ListViewModelState(
    val l1: SnapshotStateList<ItemType>,
    val l2: SnapshotStateList<ItemType>,
    val l3: SnapshotStateList<ItemType>,
    val isLoading: MutableState<Boolean>,
)

val state = remember {
    ListViewModelState(
        // fill your data...
    )
}


seems interesting but how to update this state from ViewModel ? it doesn't make sence to do this casualViewState.updateState { copy(loading = mutableStateOf(loading)) }

@Royss If you don't mind, you can just use State or SnapshotStateList in a ViewModel. Currently, this is not the case, but Google's official examples used to use State in ViewModels.
Alternatively, you could define each list as a StateFlow in the ViewModel, convert each to a state with collectAsStateWithLifecycle in Compose, and combine the states into one with derivedStateOf.
But I would just merge all three lists into single list in ViewModel and observe it as state.

Declaring a list as SnapshotStateList means that there is a single mutable instance of the list within the ViewModel. While it's acceptable to modify this list with methods like .add, .remove, etc., in my case, the state of the list is frequently updated from the server, and the client is not responsible for adding, removing, or reordering its elements.
Is there a way to use this state as a diff utility would do, where I can provide a new list and it automatically finds the differences and applies them without replacing the entire list?

You have List<ItemType> in your data model class. List is unstable type in Compose, so it will get recompose again even though the data is same.
More Info here
To fix this, use ImmutableList from kotlinx.collections.immutable which  is considered stable.
